# Async read and write API on Open62541 OPC UA

Tags: asynchronous, opc-ua, open62541

I am developing an OPC UA client that needs to connect asynchronously to a server and update its node data. I am using `UA_Client_connectAsync` to connect to the server but the async write/read APIs e.g. `UA_Client_writeValueAttribute_async` in

> Examples/client_async.c

of Examples codes are missing from source code and do not compile. Are they deprecated? What is the new API for Async read/write to the server?

I am asking this question because I have tried the `UA_Client_writeValueAttribute` API with the non-blocking `UA_Client_connectAsync` and the server node does not receive any data on its node.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. Async/multithread documentation of open62541 is very poor. No examples available (as of v1.3). I'm using Python opcua-asyncio (aka asyncua) meanwhile

Answer (score 0):

There is an async client example at https://github.com/open62541/open62541/blob/master/examples/client_async.c.

The critical ingredient is to call `UA_Client_run_iterate` repeatedly (e.g. in a loop that is executed by a separate thread).